# Key Rotation impacting secret value in Key Vault | Best practice on storing secret values

Tags: encryption, cryptography, key, azure-keyvault

I have trouble in understanding Azure Key Vault rotation. Let's consider this scenario -
I've a password to a server which I'll be storing in Key Vault. Key-Rotation is enabled in Azure KeyVault.

Q1. Should we keep this password in key vault for longer period like 1-2 years or are we compromising our server (that means we are not going to change the password for 1-2 years)?

Q2. Does rotation have any impact on secret value? I believe key-rotation will only update the keys using which secret value is encrypted. Is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 1):

> Q1. Should we keep this password in key vault for longer period like
> 1-2 years or are we compromising our server (that means we are not
> going to change the password for 1-2 years)?

Probably not a good idea to keep using the same password for 1-2 years, although it is a good start to store it in Key Vault instead of together with the source. Secrets can have versions as well, so you could periodically update the secret value with the new password and figure out a way to always use the latest form your application. For example the Secret API can return the latest version if you don't specify the version manually: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/secrets/get-secret/get-secret#uri-parameters

> Q2. Does rotation have any impact on secret value? I believe
> key-rotation will only update the keys using which secret value is
> encrypted. Is my understanding correct ?

I think the keys you are storing in your vault have nothing to do with the secret you are storing in your vault in this case. You can for example, create a new vault with only a secret in it and you will not need to add a key (nor will see one in the vault).

In my opinion, if you are storing a secret in your vault, Key Vault, as a managed service, will take care of the storage of that secret and all you need to worry about is how you are accessing your Key Vault itself and how you can keep your Key Vault secure (e.g., not allowing access from open internet and similar good practices).